# How to extract data from multiple files with Python?

Tags: dataset, text-extraction

I am new to Python, which is also my first programming language. I have a set of txt files (academic papers), I need to extract the paper ID (e.g. ID: a1111111) and abstract (e.g. ABSTRACT: .....). I have no idea how to extract this data from multiple files from multiple folders? Thanks A LOT!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your question is two part: reading files and accessing folders

- Reading files

The methods/objects in python used for reading files is in Python's documentation on chapter 7:
http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html

The basic gist is that you use the `open` method to access files that are in the same directory

`f = open('stuff.txt', 'r')`

Where `stuff.txt` is the name of the file in the same directory that your python file is in.
Calling `print f.read()` will display the text (in String format) of the file. Feel free to assign `f.read()` to a variable to capture the data.

```
>>> x = f.read()
>>> print x
This is the entire file.\n
```

Best read the documentation for all these methods, cause there are subtleties. For example, calling `f.read()` once will return the entire file contents to you, but calling `f.read()` again will return an empty string, as the "end of the file has been reached."

- Accessing Folders

Can you explain to me how exactly you'd like to access folders? In this case, it would be much easier to just put all your files in the same directory as where you are running your python file. 
However, the basic way to move around in python is to use: `os.chdir(path)` which is basically cd'ing around. You must import `os` before you use this.

Leave a comment if you'd like some more information

Comment: Thank you so much. I am able to open single file and read it and write it to another file. Now what I need to do is: I have 96 folders with multiple files in each. I need to extract the paper ID and Abstract of all of them and write in a new file. I am not sure how to do this. Again, I really appreciate your help!!!

Comment: Can you share with me where all these folders are stored? Is there some parent directory, and every directory in this parent directory contains data that you want? Or are all these directories all over the place?

Maybe this link can help you a little: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21962906/interactively-selecting-items-from-a-list

Comment: Oh, sure. I am putting my Python folder in D drive. This folder is also put there. The path is D:\Software\Python\python-3.2.2\Part1. Here part1 is my folder.

Comment: I believe you will need to put your part1 folder in the folder that you are running your script in. Then you may need to use `os.listdir` (to figure out which directories are in your current path) and `os.chir(path)` to actually move there. Then just call `open(...)` on the files in your directory

Comment: Sorry to ask a stupid question, but by "the folder that you are running your script in" do you mean the folder in C drive where python runs? Is it this one: C:\Python32? I see there are different folders in this folder, including _pycache_, DLLs, Doc, include, lib, libs, tcl. Where should I move the folder to? Thanks again.

Comment: I guess what I meant by "the folder that you are running your script in" is, where are you running your file.py? I'm assuming you're writing code in a text editor, correct? Where are you saving that code? That file is what I'm talking about

Comment: >>> import os, sys                    >>> path=('E:/Grad/LIS/LIS590 Text mining/Part1/Part1/awards_1990')
>>> dirs=os.listdir(path)
>>> for file in dirs:
 print (file)

Comment: It returned the list of file names in this folder.

Comment: You can utilize the names you received with `os.chdir(path)` to move into those directories

Comment: Don't think I need to change the path. My problems when I cannot open multiple files. The folder layers are like: part1-96 subfolders-multiple articles. I tried to use the following code which I probably should not: file=open ('E:/Grad/LIS/LIS590 Text mining/Part1/Part1/awards_1990','r'). The path I used to open file is actually one subfolder's path.

Comment: It gives me an error message "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
    file=open ('E:/Grad/LIS/LIS590 Text mining/Part1/Part1/awards_1990','r')
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'E:/Grad/LIS/LIS590 Text mining/Part1/Part1/awards_1990'".

Comment: Does `awards_1990` have a filename extension?

Comment: awards_1990 is a subfolder. There are files in it. Here is an example of one filename: a9000006. The file is txt format. The extension is not shown in the filename.

Comment: oh, I see. You can't `open()` a directory, as `open()` only reads file contents. To do this efficiently, you're going to have to feed in a list of path names of the different files to `open`. Obtaining this list of path names will require some clever python, using `os.listdir` and concatenating strings

Comment: Can you give me more information? Only knew to get filenames with os.listdir, not sure how to get the list of path names. ;-(

Comment: Oh, I figured this. I got a list of all the pathes!

Comment: Now how do I open all of them and extract three fields of information? Sorry to keep you so long. I really really appreciate your help!

Comment: You're just going to have to open them each individually and assign their text to variables. As for extracting information, I may have to delegate that to another thread. I'm sure if you googled how to parse python text, you'll get a whole lot of information

Comment: Individually? I have more than one hundred there... Anyway, thank you so much for your help! Have a great night!!

Comment: I'm sure for loops will make the task a whole lot easier. But it still does sound like a lot of work :\ That's the life of a programmer!

Comment: Also if I answered your question, best to mark it as answered (the checkmark)

Comment: Did it. Thanks again for your help~~